# Phaser3 check if preload has ran

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to use socket.io with phaser, and I'm having trouble with spawning players on connection. I'm pretty sure it's because the player's image is not loaded when the connection happens. I basically just need a way to check if the preload function is done. Something like this:

```
function preload() {
    game.load.image('player', 'client/assets/player.png');

    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(LOADED) {
            loaded = true;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

Is something like this possible, or is there another approach? Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm able to make it work like this:

```
function preload() {
    game.load.image('player', 'client/assets/player.png');

    setTimeout(() => {
        loaded = true;
    }, 100);
};
```

And in the function spawning the player:

```
let testI = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(loaded);
    if(loaded) {
        let test = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'player');
        game.physics.enable(test, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        test.body.gravity.y = 200;
        clearInterval(testI);
    }
}, 1);
```

But it's very messy and not a good solution

Comment: Are you sure that the assets are not loaded because you don't need to check if they have been loaded usually

Comment: I think so, i added a setTimeout in the preload to set a boolean loaded to true, and when i made my sprite i was waiting for the boolean loaded to be true and it worked, but that solution didn't work well and was extremely messy and unreliable

Comment: You can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56159246/2107253

Comment: It isn't exactly what i wanted but, it's still useful.