# Timer not working inside function in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a ***spawn*** function which performs some task. Before the function returns, I would like to delay some another function call.

I tried using `time.addEvent` but with no luck as it does not seem to work within the *spawn* function. However the timer works perfectly inside the *create* function.

My code so far:

```javascript
create(){
  newMethod = spawn.bind(this);
  newMethod();
}

function spawn(){
  //do stuff
  timer = this.time.addEvent({
    delay: 3000,
    callback: functionDelay,
    loop: false
  });
}

function functionDelay(){
  console.log("Works!");
}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly ? Is it like how to delay the spawn function but as you're doing it right, I don't see any problem here

Comment: How do I make the timer work inside spawn function because for some reason it does not work there.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var delayText;
var delayedEvent;

class myScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor (config)
    {
      super(config);
    }

    preload ()
    {
      this.load.image('dude', 'sprites/phaser-dude.png')
    }
   
    create () 
    {
      delayText = this.add.text(50, 50);
      delayedEvent = this.time.delayedCall(3000, this.spawn, [], this);
    }
    
    spawn()
    {
      var sprite = this.add.sprite(300, 50, 'dude')
    }
    
    update()
    {
      delayText.setText('Event.progress: ' + delayedEvent.getProgress().toString().substr(0, 4));
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/samme/phaser-examples-assets@v2.0.0/assets/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    width: 800,
    height: 600
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

game.scene.add('myScene', myScene, true);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.17.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I wanted to call the spawn function from create method. The spawn  function should do it's stuff and before returning should have a delay of few seconds.